# Promise. What is the difference between return resolve() and resolve()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

somewhere read this example:

```
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    return resolve(data)
  })
})
```

but I usually do this:

```
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    resolve(data)
  })
})
```

is there a difference?

Comment: It won't make a difference here.

Comment: I think in the first case, you can chain, but in the second, you can't

Answer (score 80):

`return resolve()` will just end the function execution as a normal `return`, that just depends on the flow of your code, If you don't want or need any more code in your function to execute, then use a `return` to exit the function

```
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    return resolve(data)
    console.log('after return') // won't execute
  })
})
```

only `resolve` will create a successful state of promise, but will execute the code execution if there are any when `return` is not used.

Remember `resolve()` and `reject()` create the state of promise, they can't be changed once the state is created, `.then` and `.catch` handlers are used for further execution,
using `return` entirely depends on your code flow. If you don't want to execute more code in that block, then `return resolve()`

```
return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err) reject(err)
    resolve(data)
    console.log('after return') // will execute
  })
})
```

it's just same as a normal `return` statement in a `function` and  has nothing to do with a promise

Comment: It would be useful to show how they both react when a `.then` state is created — i.e. one will fail, one will not.

Comment: If there is an error then we call `reject(error)` and did not return there, so will the next statement get executed - `return resolve(data)`? If yes then what are the repercussions of it?